# implement Bookmark list in java

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a program which has three JTextBox which my users can enter and check some text for right rule.

So I want add a ablitiy to my program that my users can add or remove their favorite text to a Favorite List and can create folder in Favorite list and put some text in it, such as Bookmark library in FireFox or other web browser.

I want use `RandomAccessFile` to save favorite list as a favorite source.

How do I implemet it? is there beter way to implement it? is there beter way from RandomAccessFile?

Can any one help me?

Thanks.

Comment: @kleopatra i want implement Bookmark list such as FireFox.

Comment: @mehdi I don't think you will get some code here: you'll have to write it yourself. If you encounter a problem, you can ask the question here and then you receive an answer.

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov no i dont have code here, my question is for my problem what is the best way? do i use RandomAccessFile or use XML File or etc.?

Comment: What is a JTextBox? I'm not aware of that component in the base JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be lots of approaches. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

1. Consider using **Java serialization mechanism**. You can serialize a collection of bookmarks to a file. When your app starts, you deserialize it, and get the same collection data.

   The *advantages* are: simple and easy implementation. The *disadvantages*: you can't look through stored bookmarks in a text editor or something. The same class hierarchy is to be used to load the serialized version.
2. **XML** is human-readable and provides easy interoperability. Other applications would be able to handle your list of bookmarks.

   It usually takes more resources to parse the XML and load it to memory and then to create the internal object structures. Though you can use the DOM to traverse the tree all the time, it could be not as convenient as the internal data structure using specialized classes.
3. **Random Access Files** work best with fixed record sizes. It means all the fields of your bookmarks must be fixed-length. For example, the name of a bookmark is `String`. When you write it out to a file, you store it like an array of a fixed length, let's say 20. This automatically implies that if users give a bookmark the name which length is greater than 20, the remaining characters would be lost.

   It is also easy to implement with the caveats above. Of course the records could be of variable length, but then you lose the random access to file because you cannot easily calculate the position of a specific record.

Firefox uses JSON for storing bookmarks and allows exporting to HTML. You can explore this too.

Comment: -i am using SQLite RDBMS for my purpose(SQLiteJDBC for java (hhtps://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/). FireFox is using this RDBMS for storing its data.

Answer (score 3):

You can also store bookmarks, and things you want to keep between sessions in the Preferences,
see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

Comment: @Paxinum I mean I forgot about it in my answer, and confirmed this is another option.